# Ruby on Rails - javascript(s) folder and application.js missing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails and trying to use some Javascript, but everywhere I go I see application.js mentioned, but it's nowhere to be found in my directories.

I followed the [official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and created a blog. But there is no javascript folder or application.js file under app/assets like I'm expecting.

I'm using Rails 7. During installation, I had errors with the tzinfo-data gem, but fixed it later.

[Image of the newly created blog assets folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw0D9.png)

Comment: I'm actually having the exact same issue. Just installed a fresh ruby rails etc. No JS folders after `rails new myapp --css tailwind --database=postgres`

Answer (score 5):

Run this command. `rails importmap:install`.This should solve the problem.

Comment: This command doesn't work for me, either during the initial `rails new app-name` instance or if I try the standalone command of `rails importmap:install`.  Both times I get the message "rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'importmap:install' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)".  Do you know how to get past this?   I'm considering creating a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: doesn't this delete the contents of application.js?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your preferred javascript handling gem is installed successfully. Each gem's install task will add `app/javascript/application.js`.

---

`importmap-rails` is installed by default in *rails 7*. It adds an empty *application.js*.
Install command: `bin/rails importmap:install`
*https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/blob/v1.1.0/lib/install/install.rb#L11*

---

`jsbundling-rails`
Install command: `bin/rails javascript:install:[esbuild|rollup|webpack]`
*https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/blob/v1.0.2/lib/install/install.rb#L24*

---

`shakapacker` (aka webpacker)
Install command: `bin/rails webpacker:install`
*https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker/blob/v6.4.1/lib/install/template.rb#L11*

---

You should see this bit when running `rails new`:

```rb
...
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
       rails  importmap:install
Add Importmap include tags in application layout
      insert  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
Create application.js module as entrypoint
      create  app/javascript/application.js          # <= this one
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.
add gem Webpcker to Gem file
ran bundle install
ran webpacker:install
The javascript folder was added under assets.
Rails 7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).